# How to make org agenda `follow-mode` show heading (not timestamp line)?

Tags: org-agenda, follow-mode

I like to browse history of org file with `follow-mode`.

With old Emacs version 24.5.1 (org version 8.2.10), it showed timestamp line in highlight status when I browse.

But with recent Emacs version 26.3 (org version 9.1.9), it shows heading only (not timestamp line) when I browse.

There's no specific agenda related thing for my Emacs configuration. Even though I've googled for days, I cannot find any clues. I just found one guy's posting that he had same problem. But there's no answer.

What should I do, to use `follow-mode` like in old Emacs version? Any Emacs configuration, related about it?

Comment: Can you explain your first sentence? Are you talking about org files you create? What history are you talking about? And further down, what does the agenda have to do with it? Can you provide a pointer to the other person's posting about the same problem?

Comment: yes, I meant org file I created. For agenda mode, I can set also follow-mode using 'F' key. After then, Emacs shows some part of org file with timestamp.